# How to access to $(this) when bind(this) is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a form attached to the following javascript function:

```
$('#foo').submit(function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!this.validate()) {
        return;
    }

    console.log($(this).attr('action'));
}.bind(this));
```

now the main problem is that the `submit` function attached to `#foo` is available inside a class which contains other functions, eg: `validate`:

```
Helper.prototype.validate = function()
{
    // some content
}
```

I need to access to those functions using `this`, so I attached at the end of the `submit` the code: `bind(this)` and I'm able to invoke the `validate` function of `Helper` class simply using `this.validate`.

The scenario above will cause some issue on the `$(this)` parameter, infact if I try to access to the `action` of the form, then I'll get an empty string because javascript will search the variable `action` inside the class `Helper`.

If I remove `bind(this)` I can access to the action of the form, but I'll lose the access to `validate` function.

Someone have an idea to fix this?

The generic structure of the js file is this:

```
function()
{
    Helper.prototype.bindEventHandlers = function()
    {
        $('#foo').submit(function (event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (!this.validate()) {
                return;
            }

            console.log($(this).attr('action'));
        }.bind(this));

        Helper.prototype.validate = function()
        {
           ...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't override the `this` of a function that has been `.bind`ed.   You should create an extra reference to the class object (e.g. `var self = this`) in the outer score, leaving `this` for jQuery's use

Comment: As already pointed out you can't access what you would expect to be `this` without the binding. You can, however, access the event target with `event.target`, from there you should be able to do pretty much anything

Comment: You can access the form element through `$(event.target)`, but once it was bound to another `this`, you can't access it anymore.

Comment: Is `event.target` guaranteed to be correct if you're using delegated events?

Comment: @Alnitak good question, I'm not sure. But surely there is a way out using `event.target` or `event.currentTarget`

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, when using delegated event, you can access the delegate through `event.delegateTarget` but the `event.target` remains the element on which the event were fired. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/yu30s2j5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The entire point of `bind` is that you replace the value of `this`.

If you want to have access to `this` and another value, then don't use bind. Store the value in a different variable. Consider an IIFE instead:

```
$('#foo').submit(
  function (context) {
    return function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (!context.validate()) {
        return;
      }

      console.log($(this).attr('action'));
    }
  }(this)
);
```

---

You might want to split it up to make it less unwieldy:

```
function thingy_factory(context) {
  function thingy(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!context.validate()) {
      return;
    }

    console.log($(this).attr('action'));
  }
  return thingy;
}
```

and

```
$('#foo').submit(thingy_factory(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say instead of relying on the keyword `this`, just set up a reference to the current value of `this` outside of the jQuery callback.

```
function(){
   Helper.prototype.bindEventHandlers = function(){
       var context = this;
       $('#foo').submit(function (event){
            event.preventDefault();

            if(!context.validate()){
                return;
            }

            console.log($(this).attr('action'));
        });

    }

     Helper.prototype.validate = function(){
         ...
     });
}
```

I moved Helper.prototype.validate out of the the `bindEventHandlers`, I'm assuming that's what your intention is. Might have just been a formatting error.

Answer (score 0):

Before of `$('#foo').submit` you can add `var that = this;` and validate function will be called in this way: `that.validate()`